# How to connect remote client software over VPN to DVR

Tags: windows, networking, vpn

Junior sysadmin here:  I would like to enable a remote user to view security camera footage on DVR using its client software installed on the remote machine.  Software is [Nuvico CMS Lite](http://www.nuvico.com/support/download), DVR is also Nuvico brand.  Router is a Netgear Prosafe FVS315G.

I have configured simple Hamachi VPNs for remote access to Windows machines, but not yet tried anything beyond that.  How will the software navigate private IPs over a VPN?

Inside the network, you point the software to an IP:port with the right user and pass.  Outside the network, it obviously doesn't work if I point it at our public IP with the right port, etc.  On a VPN, how do I point the software to a private IP on the other end of the VPN instead of the local network?  Does port forwarding come in to play?  I'm having trouble understanding how that works.

I don't think I need any help with my specific hardware, despite having listed it.  I'd like to know how IP will work in this situation, and perhaps a recommendation for a VPN protocol that would suite this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Hamachi gives each node its own IP. So you use that IP in the client software just like you would do normally if you were connecting to an IP on the LAN. When the OS's network stack sees the network requests from the client, it knows to route those requests over the VPN tunnel.

Comment: Right, but the issue with Hamachi is that you need to have the software running on each node, right?  This DVR is a purpose-built device without a real PC operating system, it's not a desktop computer or anything.  It can't run a Hamachi client.

Comment: Yes that's correct. If your infrastructure is unable to meet those requirements, then Hamachi will not work. Look into something like OpenVPN instead.